# Lisp defparameter use the name as arguments

Tags: function, lisp

I want to do that

```
(defparameter name (myfunct args))
```

In `myfunct` I need to reuse to assign to a variable the "name" that I use in the `defparameter`! Is it possible? How can I access to that from `myfunct`.

Comment: `defparameter` is used to bound a value to a symbol. Ask yourself how you could access to the value of a symbol before you bind it ?

Comment: ok but if I want to use the symbol "name" in myfunct is it possible?

Comment: You can use the symbol, but you cannot read its value because it has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want `myfunc` to know what `name' is. Here's how you would do that.

```
(defun myfunc (name arg1 arg2 ... argN)
  (setf var name) ;;if this is what you want
  ... do things with args and name...)
```

Then do

```
(defparameter name (myfunc 'name args...))
```

However, if you want to do this sort of thing often, you might want to create a macro that will pass `'name` for you.

Also, look up `symbol-value` if you want the value of a symbol (for example `'name`)